# Deleting a very large collection in firestore from the firebase console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very large collection of aprox 2 milions documents, all of them are outdated, and needed to be deleted.

I need to do this operation only one time, in the new data i have TTL (time to live) so i won't run into this problem again.

Sould i use the firestore console ui to delete those, or there is a better way to do this. is it possible to do this in one shot or sould i split it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single way that is pertinently better here.

The simplest option is probably to delete the documents from the console, but I often also use the [Firebase CLI's `firestore:delete` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands) - and writing your own logic through the API is equally fine. Any of these can work fine, all will need to read the documents before deleting them, and none of them is going to be significantly faster than the other.